# Limit editor to see only his Pieces in Apostrophe

Tags: apostrophe-cms

Basically I'm trying to create a system where multiple editors can post content.

But I want to limit each editor's access to only allow editing/viewing his pieces.

I already tried to search in the documentation, but I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see [apostrophe permissions](https://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/intermediate/permissions.html). What you are describing is the default behavior if you give out the `edit` rather than `admin` permission for a specific type of piece, so it is very easy to enable when editing a group.

Comment: Oops, my bad by missing that line!
Thank you !